# Google Book api , gTTs, googletrans, PyPDF4

Tags: django

I have used Google Book API, gTTs, googletrans, and PyPDF4  in my Django Project. I am trying to draw a Data Flow Diagram of my project. I am confused about the diagram should I draw like
[image: this]

My problem is that I want to know, It is valid to do as I have done in the image. Can I use API and module as a data store in Data Flow Diagram?

please help me to figure it out

Comment: You've not provided much information on what your project is and how it works, it would be very helpful to provide a bit more details.

Comment: I have updated my question please help me to figure it out And thanks for your earlier response

Comment: Use `pypdf` instead of PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4.